# Different combinations possible

Tags: code-golf, combinatorics, recursion

**Problem**

Given a value n, imagine a mountain landscape inscribed in a reference (0, 0) to (2n, 0).
There musn't be white spaces between slopes and also the mountain musn't descend below the x axis.
The problem to be solved is: given n (which defines the size of the landscape) and the number k of peaks
(k always less than or equal to n), how many combinations of mountains are possible with k peaks?

**Input**

n who represents the width of the landscape and k which is the number of peaks.

**Output**

Just the number of combinations possible.

**Example**

Given n=3 and k=2 the answer is 3 combinations.

**Just to give a visual example, they are the following:**

```
   /\     /\      /\/\
/\/  \   /  \/\  /    \
```

are the 3 combinations possible using 6 (3*2) positions and 2 peaks.

Edit:
 - more examples -

```
n  k  result
2  1  1
4  1  1
4  3  6
5  2  10
```

**Winning condition**

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest submission in bytes wins.

Comment: Is this the same as, "find the number of expressions of `n` matched parentheses pairs that contain exactly `k` instances of `()`"?

Comment: [https://oeis.org/A001263](https://oeis.org/A001263)?

Comment: @xnor yes it is.

Comment: You may want to update the challenge with a more explicit title such as _Compute Narayana Numbers_.

Comment: Could you confirm whether or not an input with `k` of zero must be handled? If so must an input with `n` equal to zero (with `k` also zero by definition) be handled?

Answer (score 7):

## Python, 40 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,k:k<2or~-n*n*f(n-1,k-1)/~-k/k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRIU8n2yrbxii/qE43TytPK00jT9dQJ1vXUFO/TjdbP/t/YnFxalGJQpqGsY6Rpq2tMRdcwEjHEChgiBAwwRQwBgqYIQRMwWYYGnAVFGXmlWio52era/4HAA)

Uses the recurrence \$a_{n,1} = 1\$, \$a_{n,k} = \frac{n(n-1)}{k(k-1)}a_{n-1,k-1}\$.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
cⱮṫ-P÷⁸
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARsA5P9qZWxsef//Y@KxruG5qy1Qw7figbj///81/zM)

Takes input as `n` then `k`. Uses the formula

\$N(n,k)=\frac{1}{n}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{k-1}\$

which I found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narayana_number).

```
cⱮṫ-P÷⁸
c        Binomial coefficient of n and...
 Ɱ       each of 1..k
  ṫ-     Keep the last two. ṫ is tail, - is -1.
    P    Product of the two numbers.
     ÷   Divide by
      ⁸  n.
```

**7 bytes**

Each line works on it's own.

```
,’$c@P÷
c@€ṫ-P÷
```

Takes input as `k` then `n`.

**7 bytes**

```
cⱮ×ƝṪ÷⁸
```

- Thanks to Jonathan Allan for this one.

Comment: Wait... tail is automatically defined as 2 numbers? (Don't know Jelly at all, just a silly question)

Comment: @Quintec There are two tail functions. One (`Ṫ`) that just takes the last element of a single argument and the one I used (`ṫ`) which takes two arguments. The fist argument is a list and the second one is a number (In my case `-1` represented by a `-` in the code) which tells you how many elements to save. Having `-1` give two elements was the golfiest way to define `ṫ`

Comment: Gotcha, thanks! I see how jelly was built for golf... hehe

Comment: Another variant for 7 f(n,k): `cⱮ×ƝṪ÷⁸`

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>33</s> 30 bytes

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to @Shaggy*

Takes input as `(n)(k)`.

```javascript
n=>g=k=>--k?n*--n/-~k/k*g(k):1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1i7dNtvWTlc32z5PS1c3T1@3Lls/WytdI1vTyvB/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGmoaRpoahpqaCvr6CIReqjAk@GWOIjBmajKkm0ECIHoP/AA)

Implements the recursive definition used by [Anders Kaseorg](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/173089/58563).

---

## JavaScript (ES7), <s>59</s> <s>58</s> <s>49</s> 45 bytes

Takes input as `(n)(k)`.

```javascript
n=>k=>k/n/(n-k+1)*(g=_=>k?n--/k--*g():1)()**2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1i4biPTz9DXydLO1DTW1NNJt44Ei9nm6uvrZurpa6RqaVoaaGppaWkb/k/PzivNzUvVy8tM10jSMNDUMNTUV9PUVDLlQZUzwyRhDZMzQZEw1gQZC9Bj8BwA)

Computes:

$$a_{n,k}=\frac{1}{k}\binom{n-1}{k-1}\binom{n}{k-1}=\frac{1}{n}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{k-1}=\frac{1}{n}\binom{n}{k}^2\times\frac{k}{n-k+1}$$

Derived from [A001263](https://oeis.org/A001263) (first formula).

Comment: [-3 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1i7dNtvWTlc32z5PS1c3T1@3Lls/WytdI1vTyvB/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGmoaRpoahpqaCvr6CIReqjAk@GWOIjBmajKkm0ECIHoP/AA) with currying.

Comment: @Shaggy Doh... Thanks. Revision #7 finally looks like revision #1 should have. :p

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 27 bytes

Three versions, all the same length:

```
(b=Binomial)@##b[#,#2-1]/#&

Binomial@##^2#2/(#-#2+1)/#&

1/(Beta[#2,d=#-#2+1]^2d##)&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78H1CUmVfi4JyfU5qb55ZflOsQkpiUkxr9XyPJ1ikzLz83MzFH00FZOSlaWUfZSNcwVl9Z7b@Cg4NCdZ5Odq0OiDLUMTSo1anOBjLyamP/AwA) (Just the first version, but you can copy and paste to try the others.)

All of these are some sort of variant on $$\frac{n!(n-1)!}{k!(k-1)!(n-k)!(n-k-1)!}$$
which is the formula that's been going around. I was hoping to get somewhere with the Beta function, which is a sort of binomial reciprocal, but then there was too much division happening.

Answer (score 2):

## APL(Dyalog), <s>19</s> <s>18</s> <s>16</s> 12 bytes

```
⊢÷⍨!×⊢!⍨¯1+⊣
```

*Thanks to @Galen Ivanov for -4 bytes*

Uses the identity in the OEIS sequence. Takes k on the left and n on the right.

[TIO](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RHXYsOb3/Uu0Lx8HQgUxHIOrTeUPtR1@L//w0V0hSMuECkCZcxmDQCkqZcAA)

Comment: `⊢÷⍨!×⊢!⍨¯1+⊣` for [12 bytes](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RHXYsOb3/Uu0Lx8HQgUxHIOrTeUPtR1@L//w0V0hSMuECkCZcxmDQCkqZcAA), argument reversed

Comment: @GalenIvanov Thanks, my tacit APL is extremely weak

Comment: My APL as not good, I just took the opportunity to give it a try, after my J solution  :)

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <strike>17</strike> 11 bytes

```
]%~!*<:@[!]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVmyrp2CgYKVg8D9WtU5Ry8bKIVox9r8ml5KegnqarZ66go5CrZVCWjEXV2pyRr6CoUKagpECgm0CZRuD2BCmEZBpyvUfAA)

Takes `n` as the right argument, `k` as the left one.
Uses the same formula as dylnan's Jelly answer and Quintec's APL solution.

### Explanation:

```
            ] - n  
           !  - choose
       <:@[   - k-1
      *       - multiplied by
     !        - n choose k
   %~         - divided by
  ]           - n
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 50 bytes

```ruby
->l,n{eval [[*n..l]*2*?*,l,n,[*1..l-=n]*2,l+1]*?/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcgxCoQwEAXQq1iP30iiCzaagwxTuLBW2SCCElHPHgexecVb1u@epz5XQ0A8ftsYCmaKxgQhR56gDSarUfVRD6G0Qr6@MnMDJ2AHq7avjfp5vkMrYv7jfJzpnAtOmJiSyJVv)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 33 bytes

```perl6
{[*] ($^n-$^k X/(2..$k X-^2))X+1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/OlorVkFDJS5PVyUuWyFCX8NIT08FyNCNM9LUjNA2rP1fnFipkKZhrKNgomnNBeEY6SiYalr/BwA)

Uses the formula

$$a_{n,k}=\binom{n-1}{k-1}\times\frac{1}{k}\binom{n}{k-1}=\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}(\frac{n-k}{i}+1)\times\prod_{i=2}^{k}(\frac{n-k}{i}+1)$$

#### Explanation

```perl6
{[*]                            }  # Product of
     ($^n-$^k X/                   # n-k divided by
                (2..$k X-^2))      # numbers in ranges [1,k-1], [2,k]
                             X+1   # plus one.
```

#### Alternative version, 39 bytes

```perl6
{combinations(|@_)²/(1+[-] @_)/[/] @_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/Ojk/NykzL7EkMz@vWKPGIV7z0CZ9DUPtaN1YBSBHP1ofRNf@L06sVEjTMNFRMNa05oJwTHUUjDSt/wMA)

Uses the formula from Arnauld's answer:

$$a_{n,k}=\frac{1}{n}\binom{n}{k}^2\times\frac{k}{n-k+1}$$

Answer (score 1):

## [Common Lisp](http://www.clisp.org/), 76 bytes

```lisp
(defun x(n k)(cond((= k 1)1)(t(*(/(* n(1- n))(* k(1- k)))(x(1- n)(1- k))))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc3LCsJADIXh/TzFWZ4URNOLm8GnaSuUkVi0wrz9NEWFikMW/xcC09@m51wKh/H6MmQakrC/20BekKCiwoUVj6xg1ANMxDNtmcQ7v5df@ysx1oD6hBjbfTXA2asDtoNTCJwfky3MbhX5EO72z82PO9T@0Qo)

Comment: You can save 2 bytes by removing the spaces after \ and after x

Comment: Just updated thanks

Comment: Suggest `(*(1- x)x)` instead of `(* x(1- x))`

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
,’$c’}P:
```

A dyadic Link accepting `n` on the left and `k` on the right which yields the count.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/nUcNMlWQgURtg9f//f/P/JgA)**

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ÇäO╪∙╜5‼O
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=80844fd8f9bd35134f&i=2+1%0A4+1%0A4+3%0A5+2%0A5+3&a=1&m=2)

I'm using dylnan's formula in stax.

Unpacked, ungolfed, and commented the program looks like this.

```
        program begins with `n` and `k` on input stack
{       begin block for mapping
  [     duplicate 2nd element from top of stack (duplicates n)
  |C    combinatorial choose operation
m       map block over array, input k is implicitly converted to [1..k]
O       push integer one *underneath* mapped array
E       explode array onto stack
*       multiply top two elements - if array had only element, then the pushed one is used
,/      pop `n` from input stack and divide
```

[Run this one](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=++++%09program+begins+with+%60n%60+and+%60k%60+on+input+stack%0A%7B+++%09begin+block+for+mapping%0A++[+%09duplicate+2nd+element+from+top+of+stack+%28duplicates+n%29%0A++%7CC%09combinatorial+choose+operation%0Am+++%09map+block+over+array,+input+k+is+implicitly+converted+to+[1..k]%0AO+++%09push+integer+one+*underneath*+mapped+array%0AE+++%09explode+array+onto+stack%0A*+++%09multiply+top+two+elements+-+if+array+had+only+element,+then+the+pushed+one+is+used%0A,%2F++%09pop+%60n%60+from+input+stack+and+divide&i=2+1%0A4+1%0A4+3%0A5+2%0A5+3&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 0):

## APL(NARS), 17 chars,  34 bytes

```
{⍺÷⍨(⍵!⍺)×⍺!⍨⍵-1}
```

test:

```
  f←{⍺÷⍨(⍵!⍺)×⍺!⍨⍵-1}
  (2 f 1)(4 f 1)(4 f 3)(5 f 2)    
1 1 6 10
```